# Collection view cells overlap animation in Bottomsheet

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, bottom-sheet

I need to apply animation like the bottom sheet where Collection View cells overlap each other when closed, and wide opened when bottom sheet is opened. I have achieved the bottom sheet with Collection View with pagination, but need to apply animation that shows only current cell and other cells behind it when bottom sheet is closed.

Here is my Bottom Sheet Class, and some images as an example what I need to achieve:

```
class ScrollableBottomSheetViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet var collection: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var headerView: UIView!

    let fullView: CGFloat = 0//50

    var partialView: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 50
    }

    let collectionMargin = CGFloat(32)
    let itemSpacing = CGFloat(10)
    let itemHeight = CGFloat(333)
    var itemWidth = CGFloat(0)
    var currentItem = 5

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        self.collection.delegate = self
        self.collection.dataSource = self

        self.collection.register(UINib(nibName:"AdsCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "default")

        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ScrollableBottomSheetViewController.panGesture))
        gesture.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        //CGFloat(219) //
        itemWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - collectionMargin * 2.0

        print(itemWidth)

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionMargin, height: 0)
        layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionMargin, height: 0)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = itemSpacing
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        collection!.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collection?.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let pageWidth = Float(itemWidth + itemSpacing)
        let targetXContentOffset = Float(targetContentOffset.pointee.x)
        let contentWidth = Float(collection!.contentSize.width  )
        var newPage = Float(self.pageControl.currentPage)

        if velocity.x == 0 {
            newPage = floor( (targetXContentOffset - Float(pageWidth) / 2) / Float(pageWidth)) + 1.0
        } else {
            newPage = Float(velocity.x > 0 ? self.pageControl.currentPage + 1 : self.pageControl.currentPage - 1)

            if newPage < 0 {
                newPage = 0
            }

            if (newPage > contentWidth / pageWidth) {
                newPage = ceil(contentWidth / pageWidth) - 1.0
            }
        }

        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(newPage)
        let point = CGPoint (x: CGFloat(newPage * pageWidth) + itemSpacing, y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)
        targetContentOffset.pointee = point
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        prepareBackgroundView()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { [weak self] in
            let frame = self?.view.frame
            let yComponent = self?.partialView
            self?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yComponent!, width: frame!.width, height: frame!.height)// - 100)
        })
    }

    @objc func panGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)

        let y = self.view.frame.minY

        if (y + translation.y >= fullView) && (y + translation.y <= partialView) {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y + translation.y, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }

        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            var duration = velocity.y < 0 ? Double((y - fullView) / -velocity.y) : Double((partialView - y) / velocity.y)

            duration = duration > 1.3 ? 1 : duration

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                if velocity.y >= 0 {
                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.partialView, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                } else {
                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.fullView, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                }

            }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                if velocity.y < 0 {
                    self?.collection.isScrollEnabled = true
                }
            })
        }
    }


    func prepareBackgroundView() {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect.init(style: .dark)
        let visualEffect = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: blurEffect)
        let bluredView = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: blurEffect)

        bluredView.contentView.addSubview(visualEffect)
        visualEffect.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        bluredView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

        view.insertSubview(bluredView, at: 0)
    }
}

extension ScrollableBottomSheetViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "default", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}

extension ScrollableBottomSheetViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // Solution
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        let gesture = (gestureRecognizer as! UIPanGestureRecognizer)
        let direction = gesture.velocity(in: view).y

        let y = view.frame.minY

        if (y == fullView && collection.contentOffset.x == 0 && direction > 0) || (y == partialView) {
            collection.isScrollEnabled = false
        } else {
            collection.isScrollEnabled = true
        }

        return false
    }

}
```

[image: Opened] [image: Opening] [image: Opened]